# adal-angular js Error: Failed to load template

Tags: angularjs, adal.js

I used adal-angular js to protect my routes.

```
  $routeProvider.
        when("/dashboard", { templateUrl: "Views/Dashboard.html", controller: "DashboardController", requireADLogin: true })
```

But when Adal getting token, I have an error in console:

**Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: Views/Dashboard.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)**

Could someone know why it happens?

Comment: Make sure the path specified for Dashboard.html file is correct?. Maybe Views folder is not at the root level, where you have your web.config.

Comment: See https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/261 - this looks similar.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue and I'm just coming upon dead ends.

Comment: @Nex Terren unfortunately no(. I investigated  src adal angular and it is library issue.

Answer (score 5):

First, forgive my english.

For me only have worked when I specified "/myUrl" in anonymousEndpoints. That skip the interceptor for this backend url.

Comment: This was actually helpful. I had this error `Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: ngToast/toast.html` and I added `anonymousEndpoints : ['ngToast/toast.html']` to adal init and the error dissapeared

Comment: but now it doesn't authenticate the view

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with this for angular ui bootstrap templates. Adding the path "uib/" to the anonymous endpoints array fixed my problem.